# 'failed to open document' in flash cs6, what should i do to recover my file?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

ive been working on a flash animation, running on mac 10.8.2, flash cs6, autosaved every 15 minutes. about 2 hours ago, i added a frame and it did the rainbow ball of death then the programme crash. i didnt think it was serious but as i opened the file again, a message popped up : 'failed to open document'. now i have tried everything, converting it to zip file then opening it. renaming etc. i do not know what to do anymore, so any help would be appreciated. you will literally save my life! i am running on a deadline and i will be forever thankful if there is anyway i could recover my file.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Managed to recover the file using a combo of ideas i found on the web.

First things first... check the file size, if it is 0 bit, your pretty much stuffed since the file is empty, sorry. If however the file is populated, then this is what i did:
1) copied the file and saved it to a new location (so working on a duplicate)
2) downloaded a rar file tool (Winrar or i used The Unarchiver for Mac)
3) Change the name of the file extension of that duplicate to .rar (you will get a warning message, accept it)
4) Double click on the .rar file to open it using the .rar extraction ap you selected - you will be asked to say where you want that file to be extracted to - i just created a new folder on my desktop. In the process of extracting that file (believe it or not it is stored up as many parts), I got error messages that 3 images that were used in the file were corrupted. I selected to continue and ignore that. I made note of the corrupted files set. 
5) Locate the problem files (mine were in a folder called "Library" in the extracted file set) and delete those images *NOTE: you should have these copied elsewhere since they are brought into flash generally. BUT you might also like to skip this step and try the step below first - i didn't - it could be that you don't actually need to delete those images. If the step below doesn't work, then come back here and try again)
6) In the new extracted file directory, there should be the same file name you want, just not as .fla but as a .xfl version. This means an uncompressed version (i have no idea what that really means) - double click on that same named file.xfl
7) This .xfl file then opened for me in Flash (i'm on CS6)
8) re save that file again as .fla, add back any images that were needed and corrupted - mine were not needed so i just left them.

I really hope this works for you! Good Luck! Vanessa